# Can you help me understand this example of fibonacci using C# closures?

Tags: c#

Attempting to learn functional C#, I ported Dustin Campbell's [fibonacci example](http://diditwith.net/PermaLink,guid,f3be3915-873b-4082-a087-871f5dd52c82.aspx) to C#3. My solution works but I have trouble understanding the last line of Nth_Fib. Isn't it weird that the agrument to formula doesn't matter? n gets instantly bound in the expression "fn => Nth_Fib(n - 1) + Nth_Fib(n - 2)" but I can't change the return type of build to Func<int>. This means I have to pass a redundant argument later?

note: the test passes

```
[TestFixture]
public class TestFibClosure{
    [Test]
    public void test_fib(){
        Assert.AreEqual(8, new FibClosure().Nth_Fib(5));
        Assert.AreEqual(1597, new FibClosure().Nth_Fib(16));
    }
}

public class FibClosure{
    private Func<int, int>[] formulaCache;

    public int Nth_Fib(int n){
        if (n <= 2) return n;
        if(formulaCache == null) formulaCache = new Func<int, int>[(n + 1)];
        Func<int, int> formula = build(n);
        //doesn't matter, n is already bound !! ??
        return formula(334567);//same as formula(n)
    }

    private Func<int, int> build(int n){
        if (formulaCache[n] == null)
            formulaCache[n] = (fn => Nth_Fib(n - 1) + Nth_Fib(n - 2));
        return formulaCache[n];
    }
}
```

Comment: @PeanutPower: Yes - what about them?

Comment: @Jon is it possible to create true closures in c# not just anonymous methods?

Comment: @PeanutPower: What exactly do you mean by "true closures"? Different people understand different things by the word "closure".

Comment: @Jon Changes inside child scope shouldn't impact within parent scope?

Comment: @PeanutPower: Yes they will. It's the *variable* which is captured (even if it's a local variable), not the value at the time of method creation. I suggest that if this is unclear, you ask a new question rather than continue in comments :) For more info, see http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/Chapter5/Closures.aspx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You *can* change the type to `Func<int>` - you've just got to do it everywhere:

```
public class FibClosure{
    private Func<int>[] formulaCache;

    public int Nth_Fib(int n){
        if (n <= 2) return n;
        if(formulaCache == null) formulaCache = new Func<int>[(n + 1)];
        Func<int> formula = build(n);
        return formula();
    }

    private Func<int> build(int n){
        if (formulaCache[n] == null)
            formulaCache[n] = () => Nth_Fib(n - 1) + Nth_Fib(n - 2);
        return formulaCache[n];
    }
}
```

You don't need an argument for the function, because the Fibonacci value it's computing is fixed - basically `formulaCache[x]` will compute `fib(x)`. The clue to this was the fact that you didn't use `fn` within the lambda expression in `build` anyway.

I'm not sure I'd say this is a terribly clear way of structuring things, admittedly...

Comment: Thanks. I missed the () => syntax for no-arg lambdas